# Jenkins - cannot create user data directory: /var/lib/jenkins/snap/docker/ : Read-only file system

Tags: azure, docker, jenkins, kubernetes, continuous-integration

I am following the following [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/jenkins-continuous-deployment) to deploy to Kubernetes from Jenkins. I have installed jenkins in my own VM. But getting following error when build is run

```
+ docker build -t myregistry.azurecr.io/my-svc:latest7 ./my-svc
cannot create user data directory: /var/lib/jenkins/snap/docker/321: Read-only file system
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

However all the directories have jenkins use as the owner, I am not sure why it is getting into permission issues.

```
poc@poc-ubuntu:~$ ls -ltr     /var/lib/
drwxr-xr-x 18 jenkins       jenkins       4096 Feb 18 16:45 jenkins
```

Comment: probably a server fault question ;)

Comment: Try "sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock"

Comment: Didn't work , do you think it's related to docker being installed using another user , I could never login using Jenkins

Answer (score 2):

Was running into the same *exact* issue. Here's the workaround (from user Gargoyle (g-rgoyle) [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/snapcraft/+bug/1620771)) that worked for me:

1. Stop Jenkins: `service jenkins stop`
2. Manually change Jenkins home dir: `mv /var/lib/jenkins /home/jenkins`
3. Change jenkins users homedir in (might not be necessary after #2): `usermod -m -d /home/jenkins jenkins`
4. Set homedir in Jenkins config: `nano /etc/default/jenkins` then go down to variable "`JENKINS_HOME`" and set value to "`/home/$NAME`"
5. Start Jenkins: `service jenkins start`

Comment: Why is this answer down-voted yet it actually works. It's a workaround for an issue that snap software has. This answer on redit agrees - https://www.reddit.com/r/devops/comments/b9jhbb/stumped_cannot_create_user_data_directory_docker/       +1 for me

Comment: Yeah, that was actually my reddit post.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you must be extending the Jenkins image. /var/lib/jenkins is a mount point. You can't create a directory at build time from dockerfile. If you need to create a folder in that directory then try to create using init script at container runtime

Comment: Refer the error thrown from docker build command. What is the line in dockerfile that is failing. Share those steps from dockerfile